# Пагинация кастомных типов постов не работает

Tags: wordpress

Создал простой каталог,

Кастомный тип записи (Custom Post Type) + Сarbon Fields

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в пагинации при нажатии далее пишет

> Страница не найдена --- Oops! That page can’t be found.

Хотя каждый блок продукта открывается нормально

**Где ошибка?**

[ccылка проект](http://wpcat.florans.md/project/)

Код страницы **archive-project.php**

```
<?php
 /*
Template Name: Шаблон Каталог
*/


get_header(); ?>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
      <div class="cell large-4 medium-4 small-12">
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'uslug-sidebar' ) ){ ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'uslug-sidebar' ); ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="cell large-8 medium-8 small-12">

        <?php
      while ( have_posts() ) :
         the_post();?>

          <?php 
         the_content();
          ?>

          <?php endwhile; // End of the loop.
      ?>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="primary" class="grid-container">
    <main id="main" class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-margin-x">

      <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'project', 
                'posts_per_page' => 6, 
                'paged' => $paged
            );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="cell large-4 medium-6 small-12 ItemCatalog">

          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <h5>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </h5>
          <div><span>Общая площадь:</span> <span><?php echo carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'list_liv_space'); ?></span></div>
          <div><span>Количество комнат</span> <span><?php echo carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'list_num_rooms'); ?></span></div>
          <div><span>Площадь основания:</span> <span><?php echo carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'list_func_area'); ?></span></div>
          <div><span>Цена:</span> <span>от <span class="list_price"><?php echo carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'list_price'); ?> руб.</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <?php  endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>



        <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12">
          <div class="navigation-page">
            <?php
 $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }    



?>
          </div>
        </div>

  </div>
  </main>
  <!-- #main -->
  </div>
  <!-- #primary -->
  <section class="work-ears">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h3>Нами построено домов из бруса за 100 лет </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-x skills">

        <div class="cell medium-4 small-12"><strong>Площадь</strong></div>
        <div class="cell medium-8 small-12"><strong>Количество сданных проектов</strong></div>
        <div class="cell medium-4 small-12"><span>до 70 м2</span> </div>
        <div class="cell medium-8 small-12">
          <span class="skill-bar">
                        <span class="skill-level  communication"><span>423</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-4 small-12">
          <span>от 70 м2 до 100 м2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-8 small-12">
          <span class="skill-bar">
                        <span class="skill-level visual-design"><span>311</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-4 small-12">
          <span>от 100 м2 до 150 м2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-8 small-12">
          <span class="skill-bar">
                        <span class="skill-level learning"><span>199</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-4 small-12">
          <span>свыше 150 м2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-8 small-12">
          <span class="skill-bar">
                        <span class="skill-level programming"><span>79</span></span>
          </span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="advantages">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h2>Наши преимущества:</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-margin-x align-center">

        <?php 

$adv = carbon_get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'adv', 'complex' );
if ( ! empty( $adv ) ): ?>
        <?php foreach ( $adv as $adv_p ): ?>
        <div class="cell large-2 medium-4 small-12 advItem">
          <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $adv_p['adv_photo'], 'full'); ?>
          <p>
            <?php echo $adv_p['adv_title']; ?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="article">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
        <div class="cell medium-12 small-12">
          <?php echo carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'short-biography'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="event">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="section_title">
        <h3>Основные этапы проектирования и строительства дома</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">

        <div class="cell medium-12 small-12">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="accordion">
              <?php $faqs = carbon_get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'faqs', 'complex' );
if ( ! empty( $faqs) ): ?>
              <?php foreach ( $faqs as $fq ): ?>
              <div class="accordion-item">

                <a>
                  <div><span><?php echo $fq['faq_num']; ?></span></div>
                  <?php echo $fq['faq_title']; ?>
                </a>
                <div class="content">
                  <?php echo $fq['faq_desc']; ?>
                </div>

              </div>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
  <!-- End Welcome Section -->
  <?php

get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильно описана база. Замените `echo paginate_links(...` на следующий код:

```
$big = 999999999;

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format'    => '/page/%#%',
    'current'   => $current_page,
    'total'     => $total_pages,
    'prev_text' => __( '« prev' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'next »' ),
) );
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь но все равно не работает

Comment: Значит, ещё где-то проблемы в коде. Я занимался пагинацией на кастомных постах буквально позавчера. Не верите мне, почитайте kama. У него то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в файле functions.php при регистрации вашего кастомного `post_type => 'project'` указать `'has_archive' => true`,